# SharedPreferences Clear Don't clear all data

Tags: android, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences

in my application, I save a lot of info in SharedPreferences with different keys, and in one particular moment, I clear all the data from SharedPreferences.

My application is being used on various devices and this operation always works well.

But yesterday, I got a problem in one of the devices, the clear operation only cleared some data from Shared Preferences.

This is the code I use to clear the SharedPreferences:

```
var localData = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences(GDefines.ABSC, FileCreationMode.Private); 
localData.Edit().Clear().Commit();
```

And this is usually the SharedPreferences file after the clear operation

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map />
```

But yesterday my SharedPreferences file have this after the clear operation

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="Cliente">MAQ.1247 TEST</string>
</map>
```

After the delete operation, I write one message in the log file and the message was written.

Any idea what might have happened to the Clear operation just having deleted some records from SharedPreferences?

Comment: what is this "GDefines.ABSC" , is this your only sharedpreference file and no other

Comment: It is not possible. Be sure to stuff the SharedPreferences  elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

use apply instead of commit(); because commit in deprecated

```
clear.apply();
```

Comment: who said `commit` is deprecated?